# Implicit import from submodules

Tags: python, module

I've got a package like this:

```
 foo/
    __init__.py
    bar.py
    baz.py
```

I'd like to have submodules' functions automatically available when I import `foo`. So if `bar.py` has `def spam()` somewhere, I'd like to be able to call it directly like `foo.spam()`. What would be the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `__init__.py`, do `from bar import spam`.

Comment: How do I make all functions in `bar.py` available?

Comment: But, don't do that. Be explicit.

Comment: Indeed, :-) If you are going to do it though you might want to understand the dunder dunder all variable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python