# Python3: implicit import from submodules, avoiding recursive imports

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

Imagine the following scenario. You're writing some module consisting of multiple files. As you're writing the code, eventually, you arrive at a situation where multiple files (let's say `main.py` and `side.py`) import each other, leading to a recursive import, a no-go.

```
module/
  main.py
  side.py
```

You decide to split `main` into multiple files: `base.py` and `advanced.py`. The former contains merely the basic definitions from `main.py` and does not make use of `side` nor any other submodules; other submodules which wish to make use of `main` should be satisfied with importing this. The latter (`advanced.py`) can freely import anything from `side`, but since `side` does not make use of `advanced`, there is no recursion. This resolves the recursive import.

Now, you're left with the following package structure:

```
module/
  side.py
  base.py
  advanced.py
```

It makes sense to put `base` and `advanced` into a subfolder `main` (thus creating a submodule), because this at least partially preserves the original package structure. Thus we obtain

```
module/
  side.py
  main/
    base.py
    advanced.py
```

But now consider a third file `third.py`, which originally imported the entire `main`:

```py
from .main import *
```

The interface to `main` was broken by the aforementioned "recursion-fixing" operator. So, how does one restore the original interface, that is, how does one make `from .main import *` import everything from both `base` and `advanced`?

---

#### Example

Original `main.py`:

```py
from .side import *

class A:
  pass

class B(C):
  pass
```

Original `side.py`:

```py
from .main import *

class C:
  pass

class D(A):
  pass
```

After restructuring, `main` is split into two files:

```py
# base.py
class A:
  pass
```

```py
# advanced.py
from module.side import *

class B(C):
  pass
```

And `side` should now be importing `main.base` instead of `main`:

```
# new side.py
from .main.base import *

class C:
  pass

class D(A):
  pass
```

---

Here are some not totally satisfactory solutions/ideas:

#### `__init__.py` shenaningans

Create `__init__.py` in the `main` submodule, and place the following into it (solution from [Implicit import from submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325867/implicit-import-from-submodules)):

```py
from .base import *
from .advanced import *
```

The problem with this is that again introduces a recursive import: recall that `side` makes use of `main.base`, thus somewhere there, there is a line of  code

```py
from .main.base import *
```

which would invoke the `__init__.py`, causing `side` to import from `advanced` as well. Which we wanted to avoid. More specifically, putting the following into the python interpreter

```py
from module.side import *
```

outputs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../module/side.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .main.base import *
  File ".../module/main/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .advanced import *
  File ".../module/main/advanced.py", line 4, in <module>
    class B(C):
NameError: name 'C' is not defined
```

The reason being that, when loading `advanced`, it attempts to load `side`. But since `side` is "already loaded" (or rather is currently being loaded), to avoid infinite recursion, python merely skips over it. But then class `C`, which is required by `advanced`, is not loaded.

#### Instead put the shenaningans in `all.py`

Instead of putting the aforementioned two lines of code inside a `__init__.py`, put it in another file `all.py`. Now, when one wants to import everything from `main`, one writes

```py
from .main.all import *
```

This is still not the same as `from .main import *`, so whenever such "recursion-fixing" restructuring of the package takes place, one would have to look for all such imports and rewrite them (by appending `.all`).

Comment: I would like to know after two and a half year if you have found a solution for yourself now?

Comment: no, I think I just accepted (as a user of python) that some stuff just doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

In many cases, this method works. that you import the module's object inside of the block, for example, if  side.py uses main.A and main.py uses side.C, You can define the simple function in each module and import A or C inside it, and the function return C or A class.

in main.py:

```py
def get_C():
    from .side import C
    return C

class A:
  pass

class B(get_C()):
  pass
```

and in side.py:

```py
def get_A():
    from .main import A
    return A

class C:
  pass

class D(get_A()):
  pass
```

In this situation, circular import error does not occur